# Start Chrome browser in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Sorry for stupid question, but how to start Chrome browser in webdriver?
I know that I have to specify the path to chromedriver.exe. Problem is I unable to download chromedriver.exe it is depricated. Also files that I found doesn't have .exe extension. I am using eclipse, Java. Please help!
I did everything step by step as suggested but its doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class chrome {

@Test public void test(){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32(2)\\chromedriver");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http:\\yahoo.com");
}

}
```

And here is the error:

FAILED: test
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\chromedriver_win32(2)\chromedriver

Comment: WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download update version of chrome driver(in below code example E://chromedriver.exe) from 
http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

```
public class ChromeTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();              
        driver.get("http://www.test.com");

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got same code. When I go to this link and downloading a file then unzip it I don't see .exe file. The only file "chromedriver" without .exe
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I find the solution. I simply add ".exe" after "chromedriver". Thank you! Solved!

Answer (score 0):

Read [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) for links and the [getting started](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) doc.  When you download, you get a zip file, extract contents which has the exe.